# lsass.exe load high when reading database with VB6

Tags: sql-server, windows, vb6, adodb

I've noticed that lsass causes the cpu to run about 50% when a VB6 Windows service is running on Server 2012 and MSSQL 2014.  Putting VB6 into the debugger, I can see that whenever a read is made to the database, lsass's cpu usage spikes.

```
dim rs = ADODB.Recordset
set rs = cnxn.Execute(sql, , adCmdText)
```

During the process, the database remains open throughout the session and there are multiple reads, making lsass take so much cpu.  I'm opening an ADODB connection with a connection string, using TCP/IP, and a sql logon (not windows logon).

What's going on and how can I stop lsass from taking so much cpu?

Comment: Doesn't look like VB6.  Are you sure that's the syntax you use?

Comment: which ADODB version do you use? you can start by tracing your query in SQLServer, try it out in Management Studio to see whats happen. after that, if you just need a rs, you could try the light version, ADOR.

Comment: I'm using ADODB 2.8.  It is the syntax that's being used.  I'll look into ADOR and see what that does.

Comment: Switched over to ADO 6.1 and ADO Recordset 6.0 but no change, lsass still doing something.

Comment: @Velocedge: maybe it's not ADODB problem, it can depend from what your Server is used for (DomainController, & so on) you could try [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and post the result, if this does help. I noticed also similar behavior with Windows Server 2012 and MSSQL 2008R2 and ended up by disabling a lot of unnecessary services.

Comment: This is a development server, not a domain controller.  Downloaded IISCrypto but it looks like it changes security protocols.  Ran the SSL Server Test and got an "A".  Do you recall what services you disabled?

Comment: @Velocedge: sorry it was a long time ago, but i can remember - among others - i also disabled unnecessary protocols in MSSQL Configuration Manager and did some other classic optimization on the target Database (disable stats on update and so on) - i was just happy to have at the end a very fast DB response and low CPU usage.

Comment: Disabled shared memory and named pipes.  Update stats already off.  No change.

Comment: You can find out which thread within lsass.exe is causing the issue but using ProcessExplorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and going into the properties of lsass.exe and clicking on the Threads tab and sorting by CPU.  That may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: ProcessExplorer shows ntdll.dll rtdestroyhandletable taking the time but I don't really understand what that means.